# mysql to excel - wrong charset output

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc, export-to-excel, cp1252

**server**: RHEL 5.5, 2.6.18-194.el5, MySQL 5.0.77

**client**: Win 7 Corporate x86, MS Excel 2010, MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver

On the server, mysql base `test`, and there is a table `rr`. Every time insert.sh is launched it truncates `test`.`rr` and writes new values to it. What I need is excel to get this data.

So I connect with ODBC driver to the base with select and everything works fine, the values writes to columns in excel, but only when I don't use cyrilic letters (and I really need to use them).
When I do, the output is like "Ñ€Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð»Ð¾ÑÑŒ Ð¿". This is UTF-8 → CP1252, I suppose.

So, my guess is, the excel is using only cp1252. I tried to drop db and create it again with CHARACTER SET latin1 (this is the mysql name for cp 1252, right?), and after that did the same with the table, but I'm still getting the same output.

I also changed character set in MySQL connector to latin1, but still no luck.
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: With a column in MySQL containing English, random Cyrillic and Chinese set up like so: `atext,varchar(50),utf8_general_ci` and a transfer to Excel on this connection string: `DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver};Server=server;DATABASE=db;PASSWORD=pw;User=usr;` and using CopyFromRecordset, I am getting the correct data in Excel.

Answer (score -1):

The charset of the Excel-file is UTF-8? For save your Excel-file with this charset try:
Save as… → Service → Charset